# Imagemagick installation throws a string error on Mac/OSX 10.8.4

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

I went ahead with the following commands to install ImageMagick:

```
1. $ brew update
2. $ brew uninstall imagemagick
3. $ brew install imagemagick
```

Throws the following error:

---

Error: version '3' should be a string

Please report this bug:

```
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_support.rb:44:in `detect_version'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_support.rb:65:in `version'
/usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb:61
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:666:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:666:in `bottle'
/usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb:60
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:90:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:175:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:410:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:22:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error in the formula. You should report it to the Homebrew devs and it'll be fixed, if it's not fixed already.

Answer (score 1):

I found help in the link below. Just follow the instructions:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23547